# Automating Addition of Product to Opportunity Line Item in Salesforce Using Flow and Apex

Tags: apex, trigger, visual-workflow, automation, opportunity-lineitem

I'm working on developing an automation process in Salesforce and could use some guidance. My goal is to automatically add a product to an existing opportunity line item list, associated with a specific opportunity record.

**Requirements:**

1. **Trigger**: The automation should be initiated under two specific conditions:

   - When a certain literal value (a specific name) is selected in a field on the opportunity record page.
   - When a numerical value in another field on the same page reaches a predefined threshold.
2. **Process**: Upon meeting these conditions, a predefined product should be automatically added to the opportunity's line item list.

**Scenario Overview:**

- **Objective**: Automatically add specific products to the opportunity line item list based on the product type selected and the corresponding number of units.
- **Conditions for Automation**:

  1. **For Cooling Systems**:

     - When 'Product_Type__c' is set to 'Cooling System' and 'Units_Count__c' is exactly 10, add a 'Pump Station' to the opportunity.
     - When 'Units_Count__c' is updated to 15, add a 'Demineralisation System'.
  2. **For Wall Panels**:

     - If 'Product_Type__c' is 'Wall Panel' and 'Units_Count__c' reaches a different threshold, add another specified product.

**Current Setup and Considerations:**

- I am considering using Salesforce Flow for this task. However, I'm open to the possibility of integrating an Apex class if necessary.

**Specific Questions:**

1. What would be the best approach to achieve this automation – using Flow, Apex, or a combination of both?
2. If using Flow, what specific elements and configurations should I focus on?
3. In case Apex is required, could you provide a basic structure or example code that aligns with this functionality?

   - Example Code: An Apex trigger that reacts to changes in 'Product_Type__c' and 'Units_Count__c', adding products to the opportunity line items as per the defined rules.

**Solutions**:

1. The best approach is using Flow. There is no need for coding a trigger although I think it would be better for the page loading time. On the other side, a Flow is easier to maintain.
   For best practice, we either use one or the other, not both.
2. 

A. **Record-Triggered Flow**:

- Initiated on record (Opportunity) update, when the (2) targeted fields fulfill specific conditions:
  `Product_Type__c: IsNull -> False & Units_Count__c: Greater than 9`

B. **Get Records Elements**:

- There are multiple 'Get Records' elements that retrieve specific Pricebook Entries based on certain criteria.

C. **Decision Elements**:

- After each 'Get Records', there is a Decision element to check whether the retrieved Pricebook Entry already has a corresponding Opportunity Line Item associated with the Opportunity.
- The Decision elements likely have two branches: one for when the line item exists ("Line Item Exists") and one for when it does not (default outcome).

D. **Create Records Actions**:

- Connected to the default outcome of the Decision elements, there are 'Create Records' actions. These actions are responsible for creating new Opportunity Line Items if the Pricebook Entry is not already associated with the Opportunity.

[image: Can you draw a schema of the current flow?]

Comment: "Best" is usually pretty subjective. General "best practice" is to limit yourself to one automation tool (i.e. use a Trigger, or a Flow, but not both). Either triggers or flows would likely work. I think flows are better for simple tasks, and triggers are better for complex tasks. You may end up having enough criteria that a trigger may make more sense (and be easier to maintain). You should look into using a "trigger framework", or at the very least having your business logic in a class that is called by the trigger (try to keep logic out of the trigger itself. Easier to test.)

Comment: As for resources to learn more, or start learning a part/feature of Salesforce, you should start by going through https://trailhead.salesforce.com . There's trails/modules there for apex and triggers. Once you get a handle on the basics, you can come back here with more specific questions. You may also want to consider using Custom Metadata Types to store the configuration (x product + y quantity = z other product) so that you wouldn't need to do a deployment and update unit tests when your product criteria changes.

Comment: @FelixvanHove There is no mention of "custom objects". Could you tell me what is not clear for you?

Comment: @FelixvanHove In Salesforce when you see "Foo__c" (Name + double underscore + "c"), it refers to **custom fields** or **custom objects API name**. If I wanted to change the topic, I would have mentioned "object" but I have been talking about fields. all along. Please read before commenting aggressively. I have not and will definitely ask "you" to do a job. Thanks.

Comment: Gosh, I really should comment less & think more! If my comments sounded aggressively, I apologize. I certainly know about custom fields and objects. It just shows my absentmindedness. Again, my apologies!